# How can I Include custom attachments in XRechnung export using odoo 15?

Tags: odoo, odoo-15, edi

In Odoo 15, when creating an invoice using the "account" app, you have the option to generate an EDI document (XRechnung) through the "Import/Export electronic invoices with UBL/CII" module (`account_edi_ubl_cii`). Additionally, with the `attachment_indexation` module, the PDF file for the invoice is integrated into the XML. However, the problem arises when trying to include custom attachments (also in PDF format), as they are currently being ignored. In the XRechnung format, these attachments should be part of the `AdditionalReferencedDocument` section (specifically, fields BT-122 and BT-123), containing the document in binary format within the XML file.

Is there a way to configure or make adjustments in Odoo 15 so that custom file attachments for an invoice are considered during the XRechnung export process?

Comment: I guess the fun starts [here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/674fa82c51e7f114e76bed69abe56809bad96350/addons/account_edi_ubl_cii/models/ir_actions_report.py) and you can see there is no fun at all. You have to override it again, call the super and add other documents as you wish. Atleast you can use some of the code again ;-)